# Use GET with date_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, get, restful-url

I use date_select to create a dropdown menu with Rails 4.

```
date_select('range', 'start_date', { :order => [:day, :month, :year], :start_year => 2008, :end_year => Date.current.year, :use_month_numbers => true, :default => session[:start_date]}, {:method => :get, :onchange => "document.dsform.submit()"})
```

However, the data is sent with a POST request instead of GET. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `method: get` attribute should be defined on the **form** and not on the input tag.